# Como mesclar imagens e texto com PHP

Tags: php, imagem, gd, imagemagick

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando automatizar um processo de criar crachás para um evento.

Quero que quando o usuário preencha as informações do formulário (nome, empresa, e-mail e foto), as informações preenchidas completem as lacunas da imagem e torne tudo como uma única imagem JPEG.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas cheguei a um certo ponto que já não sei mas como proceder.

Sou iniciante em PHP.

Este código eu peguei na internet e modifiquei de forma que eu consiga atingir o objetivo.

```html
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// link to the font file no the server
$fontname = 'font/Roboto-Regular.ttf';
// controls the spacing between text

//JPG image quality 0-100
$quality = 100;

function create_image($user){
$height = 0;
$i=30;

global $fontname; 
global $quality;
global $im;
$file = "covers/".md5($user[0]['name'].$user[1]['name'].$user[2]['name']).".jpg"; 

// if the file already exists dont create it again just serve up the original 
//if (!file_exists($file)) { 


// define the base image that we lay our text on
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("pass.jpg");
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('fotos/foto.jpg');

// setup the text colours
$color['grey'] = imagecolorallocate($im, 54, 56, 60);
$color['green'] = imagecolorallocate($im, 55, 189, 102);

// this defines the starting height for the text block
$y = imagesy($im) - $height - 550;
$imgy = imagesy($src) - $height - 550;

imagecopymerge($im, $src, 124, 463, 0, 0, 353, 354, 100);


// loop through the array and write the text 
foreach ($user as $value){
 // center the text in our image - returns the x value
 $x = center_text($value['name'], $value['font-size']); 
 imagettftext($im, $value['font-size'], 0, $x, $y+$i, $color[$value['color']], $fontname,$value['name']);
 // add 32px to the line height for the next text block
 $i = $i+36;
}

// create the image
imagejpeg($im, $file, $quality);

//}

return $file; 
}

function center_text($string, $font_size){

global $fontname;

$image_width = 1004;
$dimensions = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $fontname, $string);

return ceil(($image_width - $dimensions[4]) / 5.0);    
}



$user = array(

array(
 'name'=> 'Nome',
 'font-size'=>'36',
 'color'=>'grey'),

array(
 'name'=> 'Cargo',
 'font-size'=>'16',
 'color'=>'grey'),

array(
 'name'=> 'Organização',
 'font-size'=>'13',
 'color'=>'green'
 )
);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$error = array();

if(strlen($_POST['name'])==0){
 $error[] = 'Please enter a name';
}

if(strlen($_POST['job'])==0){
 $error[] = 'Please enter a job title';
}  

if(strlen($_POST['email'])==0){
 $error[] = 'Please enter an email address';
}

if(count($error)==0){

 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['foto']['size'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
  $folder="fotos/";
 
  move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);

 $user = array(

  array(
   'name'=> $_POST['name'], 
   'font-size'=>'27',
   'color'=>'grey'),
  
  array(
   'name'=> $_POST['job'],
   'font-size'=>'16',
   'color'=>'grey'),
  
  array(
   'name'=> $_POST['email'],
   'font-size'=>'13',
   'color'=>'green'
   ),
  array(
   'name'=> $_POST['email'],
   'font-size'=>'13',
   'color'=>'green'
   )
  
  ); 
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("pass.jpg"); 
 imagecopymerge($im, imagecreatefromjpeg($folder.$file), 124, 463, 0, 0, 353, 354, 100);
}

}

// run the script to create the image
$filename = create_image($user);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Gerar Crachás</title>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>
input{
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:8px;
 font-size:14px;
 width:300px;
}

.submit{
 width:110px;
 background-color:#FF6;
 padding:3px;
 border:1px solid #FC0;
 margin-top:20px;} 

 </style>

</head>

<body>

 <img src="<?=$filename;?>?id=<?=rand(0,1292938);?>" /><br/><br/>

 <ul>
  <?php if(isset($error)){

   foreach($error as $errors){

    echo '<li>'.$errors.'</li>';

   }


  }?>
 </ul>

 <a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>">Clique aqui para Baixar</a>

 <p>You can edit the image above by typing your details in below. It'll then generate a new image which you can right click on and save to your computer.</p>

 <div class="dynamic-form">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){echo $_POST['name'];}?>" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
   <label>Job Title</label>
   <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['job'])){echo $_POST['job'];}?>" name="job" placeholder="Job Title"><br/>
   <label>Email</label>
   <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){echo $_POST['email'];}?>" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
   <label>Add Photo</label>
   <input type="file" name="foto" placeholder="Foto"/><br>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Image" />
  </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O 1º exemplo desse script aqui: [Adicionando Texto à imagem com PHP](https://php.eduardokraus.com/adicionando-texto-a-imagem-com-php). Depois vc pode ajustar fonte, posicionamento, criar um PDF a partir da imagem, etc.

**Usando fonte truetype, posicionamento de texto, gravação em um diretório e retorno no navegador:**

```
    # Header informando que é uma imagem JPEG
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    # Declaração das variáveis usadas
    $imgName = strtoupper(substr(md5(date(DATE_RFC822)), 0, 20));
    $imgPath = "cache/$imgName.jpg";
    $imgQuality = 90;
    # Carregar imagem já existente no servidor
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("imagem.jpg");
    $font = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf";
    # Cores de saída
    $black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
    # Texto que será escrito na imagem
    $texto = urldecode("Texto inserido na imagem\n");
    $texto.= $imgName;
    # Posicionamento
    $bbox = imagettfbbox(10, 45, $font, $texto);
    $x = $bbox[0] + (imagesx($img) / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) - 130;
    $y = $bbox[1] + (imagesy($img) / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2) - 40;
    # Escrever na $img
    imagettftext($img, 25, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $texto);
    # Envia a imagem para o arquivo
    imagejpeg($img, $imgPath, $imgQuality);
    # Mostra a imagem no navegador
    imagejpeg($img, NULL, $imgQuality);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: Bom, era exatamente o quê eu precisava. Mas está um pouco incompleto. Gostaria de saber como eu posso incorporar o upload de imagem neste código.
Depois de tratar o upload e mover para o diretório, tenho dificuldade em utilizar o metódo "imagecopymerge()" com o arquivo em que foi feito upload, ele dá erro no segundo parâmetro que é responsável pelo caminho do diretório.

Comment: Não entendi direito o que vc quer, mas editei a resposta acrescentando algumas funcionalidades. Agora o código grava a imagem **(imagejpeg($img, $imgPath, $imgQuality);** no diretório **$imgPath** antes de retornar o buffer pro navegador. Lembre-se de dar as permissões corretas para o servidor poder gravar em **$imgPath**.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado .

Answer (score 0):

Já precisei fazer algo parecido para gerar assinaturas para e-mails da empresa onde trabalho. A solução que eu encontrei foi posicionar os elementos com css e usar uma [biblioteca](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) que tira um screenshot dos elementos html, aí eu escondia os originais e mostrava apenas o screenshot tirado. Dê uma olhada na [biblioteca](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas), ou no [meu projeto](https://github.com/ijrodrigues/Gerador-de-assinaturas-png), talvez te ajude.

Comment: Gostei bastante do seu projeto, parabéns! No meu caso vou dar preferência por um código "limpo" porque preciso reutilizar algumas funções nativas do PHP, mas com certeza vou retirar algumas ideias do seu projeto.